# Jquery regex replace opening and closing tags is in string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Here is my html that I am trying to locate in a string, and replace whole thing (itself and its children) with new html.

I want to replace everything between and including `<div id="image_insert">...</div>` with (for example) "test".  Is this possible?

I've tried:

```
content.replace('<div id="image_insert">[entire string in here]</div>', 'test');
content.replace(/<div id="image_insert">[entire string in here]</div>/g, 'test');
content.replace(/<div id="image_insert"></div>/g, 'test');
```

But with no effect.  Any thoughts?  Not very good at regex's.

Comment: Try : `content.replace(/<div id="image_insert">[entire string in here]<\/div>/g, 'test');`

Comment: The [entire string in here] can be different, the parent tags are the static thing.

Comment: look in the console, you should have an error, @Cherniv's example should work

Comment: If you have nested <div> this can't be done with javascript regex.

Comment: Why oh why are you not putting it in an element and replacing the element using the DOM API? It's much simpler anyway. Regex is a [broken approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1348195) to parse HTML. I can name 10 counter examples for which the code in the accepted answer fails out of my hat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape slash in the `</div>`. And `(.*)` is regular expression for any possible characters. So this will work:

```
   content = content.replace(/<div id="image_insert">(.*)<\/div>/g, 'test');
```

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/J84nt/1/

Comment: See above comment, The [entire string in here] can be different, the parent tags are the static thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to modify the DOM, or only the string? If your goal is to modify the DOM, then you can use jQuery's [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) instead of RegEx.

Comment: I am getting the html from a div, and need to replace (see above) within that html string.  So I'm getting the html of <h1>Test</h1><div id="image_insert">[entire string in here (is dynamic)]</div>, and only want to replace <div id="image_insert.... with (for example) "test".